# $_FILES['File']['type'] in PHP doesn't work when a file is uploaded from Flash AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I use this PHP code for uploading audio(mp3) file from Flash AS3 to server. It works when a file upload from html form but it doesn't work when the file upload from AS3 side.  When I remove *$_FILES['Filedata']['type']=='audio/mpeg'* condition it also work with AS3. I don't know what is the problem.

```
<?php
if($_FILES['Filedata']['size'] < 500000  &&  $_FILES['Filedata']['type']=='audio/mpeg'){

$uploads_dir = './upload/';
if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], 
 $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ){
        echo 'ok';
        exit();
    }
}
echo 'error';
exit();

}else 
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Add a `echo $_FILES['Filedata']['type'];` and `echo $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];`  above the `if` statement and see what it outputs.

Comment: What about the second `echo` statement?

Comment: 61380 . The problem is the file type. Why it works properly when the file uploaded from html but it doesn't work when uploaded from AS3.

Comment: You should remove this check, it is not to be trusted, since type in `$_FILES` array is sent by client. Attacker can easily send malicious php file with type `audio/mpeg` and take over your server. You have to check uploaded file on server side and make sure they are stored in non-executable form.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller.Thanks for your help and suggestion.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller. If I remove the execute permission from my upload directory, it will be secure?

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading the file using the html standard as multipart/form-data ?

If not, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854552/2858188

Comment: I said it works properly when uplod from HTML. I need to upload from AS3.

Comment: I meant that are you adding the headers for the AS3 code.
try the link might help.
[Creating a Reusable Flash Uploader with ActionScript 3.0 and PHP](http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-reusable-flash-uploader-with-actionscript-30-and-php--active-1952)